pasar variable a url javascript/jquery
Hola a todos espero esten bien... tengo el siguiente dilema
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="botonir">Documento</button>

tengo este boton el cual al ser oprimido llama esta funcion: botonir
No se como pasarle esa id a la URL ya que se crea y se pasa de php a javascript mas arriba y luego esas variables JavaScript están allí disponibles en este script...
<script>    
        $(document).ready(function() {    
          .....
          .....
eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.bind('click', function() {
                    $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                    $('#ModalEdit #id_contrato').val(event.id_contrato);

<?php foreach($events as $event): 
                    
                $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
                $fechainicial = explode(" ", $event['fechainicial']);
},
    
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            ]
        });
]
        });
        function edit(event){
            start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            if(event.end){
                end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            }else{
                end = start;
            }
            
            id = id;
            color = color;
            
            $.ajax({
             url: 'editEventDate.php',
             type: "POST",
             data: {id:id, color:color},
             success: function(rep) {
                    if(rep == 'OK'){
                        alert('Evento se ha guardado correctamente');
                    }else{
                        alert('No se pudo guardar. Inténtalo de nuevo.'); 
                    }
                }
            });
        }
//--------------------------------
$("#botonir" ).click(function() {
window.open("https://pagina.com/reporte/generarrecorda.php?id="+event.id, "Generar Documento", "width=500, height=500")
}); 
    });
//--------------------------------
</script>

como hago para enviar esa id (variable id) a la URL ya que me sale UNDEFINIDO en la ventana que abre ...
Hola y mil gracias por responder.. lastima este foro no me deja pasar el codigo completo... aca paso unos apartes...
este es el codigo de la funcion del boton
$("#botonir" ).click(function() {
window.open("generarrecorda.php?id="<?php $_GET['id'] ?>, "Generar Documento", "width=500, height=500")
});
    });

pero no he podido pasar la variable id cargada...
he usado:

$_GET['id']

id $event['id']

+event.id

id
eventRender: function(event, element) {
element.bind('click', function() {
$('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
$('#ModalEdit #id_contrato').val(event.id_contrato);
$('#ModalEdit #cedula').val(event.cedula);
$('#ModalEdit #numero').val(event.numero);
$('#ModalEdit #nombre').val(event.title);
$('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
$('#ModalEdit #cargo').val(event.cargo);
$('#ModalEdit #municipio').val(event.municipio);
$('#ModalEdit #imagen').val(event.imagen);
//$('#ModalEdit #periodojunto').val(event.periodojunto);
$('#ModalEdit #start').val(event.start2);
$('#ModalEdit #end').val(event.end2);
$('#ModalEdit #fechainicial').val(event.fechainicial2);
$('#ModalEdit #duracion').val(event.duracion);
$("#imagen").attr("src", "https://pagina.com/reporte/fotos/foto-"+event.imagen);
$('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
});
             },
             eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

                 edit(event);

             },
             eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

                 edit(event);

             },
             events: [
             <?php foreach($events as $event):

                 $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                 $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
                 $fechainicial = explode(" ", $event['fechainicial']);

                 //--------------------------
                 if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                     $start = $start[0];
                 }else{
                     $start = $event['start'];
                 }
                 //---------------------------------
                 if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                     $end = $end[0];
                 }else{
                     $end = $event['end'];
                 }
                 //---------------------------------
                 if($fechainicial[1] == '00:00:00'){
                     $fechainicial = $fechainicial[0];
                 }else{
                     $fechainicial = $event['fechainicial'];
                 }


             ?>
                 {
                     id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                     numero: '<?php echo strtoupper($event['numero']); ?>',
                     title: '<?php echo eliminar_acentos(strtoupper($event['title'])); ?>',
                     cargo: '<?php echo strtoupper($event['cargo']); ?>',
                     municipio: '<?php echo strtoupper($event['municipio']); ?>',
                     start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                     start2: '<?php echo strtoupper(fechaCastellano($start)); ?>',
                     end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                     end2: '<?php echo strtoupper(fechaCastellano ($end)); ?>',
                     fechainicial: '<?php echo $fechainicial; ?>',
                     fechainicial2: '<?php echo strtoupper(fechaCastellano($fechainicial)); ?>',
                     color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
                     duracion: '<?php echo strtoupper($event['duracion']); ?>',
                     imagen: '<?php echo $event['id_contrato']; ?>',
                     id_contrato: '<?php echo $event['id_contrato']; ?>',
                     cedula: '<?php echo number_format($event['id_contrato'], 0, ',', '.'); ?>',
                 },

             <?php endforeach; ?>
             ]
         });



deberia dejarme tomar la id que muestra en eso codigos.. no se si deba meter el codigo dentro del foreach por que noto que por fuera es que no lo toma....

Si usas Ajax no necesitas pasar el dato usando window.open. Estás mezclando conceptos.

nooo no es ajax si notas es pasar las variables a un boton que abre una URL con las variables para pasarlas via GET luego..
id: '',
numero: '',
por lo que si notas hay unas variables  en este boton:
$("#botonir" ).click(function() {
window.open("generarrecorda.php?id=10", "Generar Documento", "width=500, height=500")
});
});

Sí. Pero en el código de más arriba usas Ajax. ¿Por qué quieres pasarlo vía URL cuando es mejor hacerlo con ese Ajax que ya tienes?

no es mas complicado... pues es solo un boton que abra una URl con las variables pero no se por que al poner las variables en la misma no salen... debria noo!!

Si la quieres pasar vía URL, tendrás que usar la super global $_GET, por ejemplo $_GET['id'] . Pero no entiendo por qué crees que es más complicado pasarlo vía Ajax cuando ya estás usando Ajax en tu código. Lo que estás haciendo es mandar datos por dos vías distintas pudiéndolo hacer por una sola.

Dices No se como pasarle esa id a la URL ... cual id??  No se entiende tu pregunta, donde esta esa id?

@Yussef gracias por responder modifique parte de la pregunta... mostrando lo que pides pues lastoma este foro no me dejaba poner el codigo completo

Nunca es necesario poner el código completo @Eduardo. No se debe poner el código completo. Para buscar ayuda con la depuración no queremos pasar dos horas leyendo todo tu código e intentando entenderlo, para eso existe el concepto [mre]. Debes mostrar tan solo el código mínimo necesario para que podamos reproducir tu problema.

@Benito-B  NUNCA he dicho que quiero pasar el código Completo ni que tampoco quieras depurarlo, solo pongo los apartes del código pues me preguntan de que lado quiero tomar la ID que quero pasar a la URL.... saludos

Hola @Eduardo, pero mi consulta es más simple. Lee solo las primeras 3 oraciones de tu pregunta. En la última dices No sé cómo pasarle esa id a la URL, lo único con id que veo es la id del botón botonir, es esa id la que quieres pasar??

En la parte que pones window.open("generarrecorda.php?id=" ... etc. usa un echo:  window.open("generarrecorda.php?id="... etc.

bueno al parecer la ID es pasada a una variable Jquery (JavaScript) $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id); pero mas abajo se ve que pasa de php a javaScript id: '',  noto tambien que en una deesas lineas se usa asi $("#imagen").attr("src", "https://pagina.com/reporte/fotos/foto-"+event.imagen); por loq ue supongo que es crear una URL en JQUERY y pasarla a ese boton..
